# How can I change elements row-wise in a NumPy array based on several conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I would like to replace the maximum value in every row of a 2D array by 0 if the value is found at a specific index position (e.g. every second element in each row) and if that value is smaller than a specified threshold. This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 5, 3, 3], 
                [5, 6, 9, 3], 
                [2, 9, 3, 3], 
                [1, 4, 2, 2]])

output = np.where((arr == np.amax(arr[:,1]) & (arr < 7)), 0, arr)
```

In `arr`, each element at index position 1 should be changed to 0 but only if it is the maximum value in the row and if it is smaller than 7 (for instance). The output array should also keep the original values at all other positions. The output I'd like to get looks like this:

```
np.array([[1, 0, 3, 3], 
          [5, 6, 9, 3], 
          [2, 0, 3, 3], 
          [1, 0, 2, 2]])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the third row must have a 9 not a 0 I think

Comment: couldn't understand the condition of the seccond element of every row

Comment: I mean at index position 1. For example, in the first row: 5, second row: 6 etc.

Comment: okey you only put 0 if the maximun occurs in the seccond column?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT***: To make a generalization to `NxM` matrices it's necesary to change the `len(arr)` to `arr.shape[1]` in the section of `col_mask`.
I added this to the code.

---

As a comment, the result should be:

```
np.array([[1, 0, 3, 3], 
          [5, 6, 9, 3], 
          [2, 9, 3, 3], 
          [1, 0, 2, 2]])
```

with a 9 in (2,1) because this is higher than threshold.

I would solve this using masks to check where the conditions occurs:

1. a bool mask of the maximum values in the matrix.
2. mask for threshold (applied to every maximum)
3. mask for column number (applied to every row)
4. combine al masks and set to 0 values where the masks intersects

Short version of code:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 5, 3, 3], 
                [5, 6, 9, 3], 
                [2, 9, 3, 3], 
                [1, 4, 2, 2]])

thresh = 7 #threshold of value only put 0 if max y lower than this
col = 1 #only put 0 if maximum ocurrs in this column

max_vals = np.max(arr,1,keepdims=True) #get max values
maximum_as_bool = arr == max_vals #create a bool mask where of every max

col_mask = np.zeros(arr.shape[1],dtype=np.bool)
col_mask[col] = True #mask of columns values

thresh_mask = max_vals<thresh #mask for threshold

all_conditions  = maximum_as_bool*thresh_mask*col_mask
arr[all_conditions ]=0 #combine masks
```

---

Part by part explained:

1. bool matrix of maximums:

```
max_vals = np.max(arr,1,keepdims=True) #get max values
maximum_as_bool = arr == max_vals #create a bool mask where of every max
```

wich results in :

```
max_vals = [[5],
            [9],
            [9],
            [4]]
maximum_as_bool = [[False,  True, False, False],
                  [False, False,  True, False],
                  [False,  True, False, False],
                  [False,  True, False, False]]
```

2. and 3.
   Mask for threshold (applied in every column) and a mask for column number (applied in every row):

```
thresh = 7 #threshold of value only put 0 if max y lower than this
col = 1 #only put 0 if maximum ocurrs in this column

col_mask = np.zeros(arr.shape[1],dtype=np.bool)
col_mask[col] = True #mask of columns values

thresh_mask = max_vals<thresh #mask for threshold
```

wich outputs:

```
col_mask = [False, False, False, False]
thresh_mask = [[ True],
               [False],
               [False],
               [ True]]
```

4. 

for last, combine al masks to get places where all conditions meets then set this values to 0:

```
all_conditions = maximum_as_bool*thresh_mask*col_mask

arr[all_conditions ]=0 #combine masks
```

wich outputs

```
all_conditions = [[False, False, False, False],
                  [False, False, False, False],
                  [False, False, False, False],
                  [False, False, False, False]]

arr = [[1, 0, 3, 3],
       [5, 6, 9, 3],
       [2, 9, 3, 3],
       [1, 0, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Many thanks, that works perfectly. Thanks also for the detailed explanations, which are very helpful.

Comment: I feel that bool indexing is sometimes (most times) confusing so the explanation is a must in this cases. If you have any doubt let me know

Comment: I just tried the code with another data set (array with 3 rows and 4 columns) and I get a value error when running ```all_conditions  = maximum_as_bool*thresh_mask*col_mask```: ```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4), (3,).``` I wonder why this occurs, as the structure of the data is exactly the same (only the array is smaller).

Comment: yup, that's because this was thinked to square matrices. If you want to generalize have to change the `len(arr)` inside the `np.zeros` to `arr.shape[1]`. I will modify the full answer to put that!

Comment: That did indeed fix it. Thanks!